# Conjecture: Range[1,n^2,n] has at least one item which is just the product of two primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Conjecture(**Two Primes Modulo Conjecture**): For any integer n>2, there exists two primes p,q satisfy: $p*q\equiv 1  \text{mod} (n)$ and $ p*q<n^2 $.

In other words, Range[1,n^2,n] = {1, n+1, 2n+1,..., (n-1)n+1} has at least one item which is just the product of two primes.

```
In[160]:= n = 3;
Dynamic[n]
While[
 NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, PrimeOmega[n* # + 1] != 2 &] < n, n++]
n

Out[161]= 327 468
Out[162]= $Aborted
```

23*997=22931 22931%2293==1

Do you think this conjecture is True or False? I think this is not a very difficult question, but I don't know how to prove still.

Comment: It is probably a very difficult question, unfortunately.

Comment: Dirichlet's theorem tells us that we can do this if we drop the condition on the size of $p,q$ but I don't believe much is known about the minimal primes one can produce this way.  This link is somewhat relevant:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/80865/least-prime-in-a-arithmetic-progression    To be sure, for this question you can use many arithmetic progressions...but I still doubt that much is known.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is known at present. Using Linnik's theorem it can be shown that there is such a number $\ll n^{10}$. On GRH this can be improved to $\ll n^4\log^4 n$ (slightly better: $<(1+o(1))\varphi(n)^4\log^4n$).

Comment: I don't understand your answer really..... Are you answering another question? What on Generalized Riemann hypothesis?

Comment: @aboy: You asked if there was a certain kind of semiprime up to n^2. I said (more or less) that we can't prove n^2 but we can prove n^10 and n^4 would follow from a well-known mathematical guess called GRH, the generalized Riemann hypothesis.